# How to force java web start to start the splash screen and later window on same display monitor with IE

Tags: java, browser, java-web-start, multiple-monitors

Scenario: Laptop has multiple monitors, use projector as second monitor.

Bring IE to the projector monitor, type jnlp path to start the java web start, but the Java splash screen (for first time, later time it will show application's splash window) shown on laptop own monitor (first monitor of the system).  And so is the later window of the java web start application.  I need to manually drag the window but the audience missed the splash window.

Question: is there a way to tell javaws to show Java splash screen, and application splash screen for future to appear on the same display with the browser that started it?  Also, how to let the java application to know which display it was on since the user might put IE on any monitor he has?

Comment: Often, a "second monitor" is just an extension of the same virtual "desktop".  If you had a 1024x768 primary (for example), and a 1024x768 secondary, then the upper left corner of the primary would be (10,10) ... and the upper left corner of the secondary would be (1023, 10).  You could position your windows (including the splash screen) accordingly.  Try it, and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Java application can definitely move itself to a different monitor.  The question is how to detect where the browser is.  And also how to notify javaws to show the splash window on the "detected" monitor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JWS splash, unlike the AWT based [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html), does not provide any programmer control.  So the answer to your question is 'it cannot be done'.

Comment: Can I disable the default JWS splash?  Which means, initially, I don't want the "Java" splash screen to show up for the first time.  If that can be done, I plan to fake a splash screen on the correct monitor using javascript.

Comment: *"Can I disable the default JWS splash? Which means, initially,.."*  It depends what you mean. The 'first launch' splash is always the default Java one, even if you specify a splash.  With some hackery, you might use a small or transparent image for subsequent splashes.  All seems like 'futzing' though.  If you are previewing this for a potential client, make a video of it on a single screen machine.  If it is at time of deployment that more concerns you, take a 'chill-pill'.  Users with multiple monitors will be used to odd things like this happening, and probably won't even notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question partially, you can change your splash screen through in the JNLP file changing the icon tag attributes.

References.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#206

https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/changing_the_java_web_start